# How to insert custom Groovy method into the report?

Tags: groovy, jasper-reports

I would like to create a really simple jasper reports with jaspersoft studio. I want to use a groovy function just to return a string which will be included in my report.

The problem is I don't really know how to link the groovy file with the jrxml file.

Any ideas ?

Here's the code and you will notice that I try to call the `GetName()` function:

**Blank_A4.jrxml file :**

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="033445e4-caf8-491f-baf8-453af181b515">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="220" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="7af5e6b8-02c1-4a18-b40c-f2dd1bc90268"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[GetName()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title> ...
```

**Blank_A4.groovy  file :**

```
class Example {
   static def GetName() {
      return "Hello";
   } 

   static void main(String[] args) {
      GetName();
   } 
}
```

These two files are in the same folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

different options:

1. compile your groovy classes into jar, and add jar as a library to your jasper project. Call to function will be like this: `Example.GetName()`
2. in Jaspersoft Studio it's possible to create `Functions Library`
   https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-studio-expression-editor-how-extend-it-and-contribute-your-own-functions-part-2
3. if you run your report from groovy environment (not from studio) it's possible to add folder with groovy files (classes)  as a classpath to groovy engine classloader. So it will be possible to use dynamic groovy files compilation.